# (Stored Procedure) how to query yearly report display in 12 months

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to know which part I left it. because i getting different aspect result.

```
select @fYear as [Year],
        main.Description,
        --CardType,
        (case when COUNT(jan.CardType) is null then '0' else COUNT(jan.CardType) end ) as Jan_Collection,
        (case when COUNT(feb.CardType) is null then '0' else COUNT(feb.CardType) end ) as Feb_Collection,
        (case when COUNT(mac.CardType) is null then '0' else COUNT(mac.CardType) end ) as mac_Collection,
        (case when COUNT(apr.CardType) is null then '0' else COUNT(apr.CardType) end ) as apr_Collection,
        (case when COUNT(may.CardType) is null then '0' else COUNT(may.CardType) end ) as may_Collection,
        (case when COUNT(jun.CardType) is null then '0' else COUNT(jun.CardType) end ) as jun_Collection,
        (case when COUNT(jul.CardType) is null then '0' else COUNT(jul.CardType) end ) as jul_Collection,
        (case when COUNT(aug.CardType) is null then '0' else COUNT(aug.CardType) end ) as aug_Collection,
        (case when COUNT(sep.CardType) is null then '0' else COUNT(sep.CardType) end ) as sep_Collection,
        (case when COUNT(oct.CardType) is null then '0' else COUNT(oct.CardType) end ) as oct_Collection,
        (case when COUNT(nov.CardType) is null then '0' else COUNT(nov.CardType) end ) as nov_Collection,
        (case when COUNT(dis.CardType) is null then '0' else COUNT(dis.CardType) end ) as dis_Collection
        from BKM_Requestor as main
                left join BKM_Party as b on  main.requestorid = b.requestorid
                left join tblBlue as jan on b.partyid = jan.partyid and MONTH(jan.AppliedDate) = '1' and YEAR(jan.AppliedDate) = @fYear and jan.CardType = 'K' and b.PartyId = jan.PartyId
                left join tblBlue as feb on b.partyid = feb.partyid and MONTH(feb.AppliedDate) = '2' and YEAR(feb.AppliedDate) = @fYear and feb.CardType = 'K' and b.PartyId = feb.PartyId
                left join tblBlue as mac on b.partyid = mac.partyid and MONTH(mac.AppliedDate) = '3' and YEAR(mac.AppliedDate) = @fYear and mac.CardType = 'K' and b.PartyId = mac.PartyId   
                left join tblBlue as apr on b.partyid = apr.partyid and MONTH(apr.AppliedDate) = '4' and YEAR(apr.AppliedDate) = @fYear and apr.CardType = 'K' and b.PartyId = apr.PartyId  
                left join tblBlue as may on b.partyid = may.partyid and MONTH(may.AppliedDate) = '5' and YEAR(may.AppliedDate) = @fYear  and may.CardType = 'K' and b.PartyId = may.PartyId   
                left join tblBlue as jun on b.partyid = jun.partyid and MONTH(jun.AppliedDate) = '6' and YEAR(jun.AppliedDate) = @fYear  and jun.CardType = 'K' and b.PartyId = jun.PartyId   
                left join tblBlue as jul on b.partyid = jul.partyid and MONTH(jul.AppliedDate) = '7' and YEAR(jul.AppliedDate) = @fYear  and jul.CardType = 'K' and b.PartyId = jul.PartyId   
                left join tblBlue as aug on b.partyid = aug.partyid and MONTH(aug.AppliedDate) = '8' and YEAR(aug.AppliedDate) = @fYear and aug.CardType = 'K' and b.PartyId = aug.PartyId    
                left join tblBlue as sep on b.partyid = sep.partyid and MONTH(sep.AppliedDate) = '9' and YEAR(sep.AppliedDate) = @fYear  and sep.CardType = 'K' and b.PartyId = sep.PartyId   
                left join tblBlue as oct on b.partyid = oct.partyid and MONTH(oct.AppliedDate) = '10' and YEAR(oct.AppliedDate) = @fYear  and oct.CardType = 'K' and b.PartyId = oct.PartyId   
                left join tblBlue as nov on b.partyid = nov.partyid and MONTH(nov.AppliedDate) = '11' and YEAR(nov.AppliedDate) = @fYear    and nov.CardType = 'K' and b.PartyId = nov.PartyId 
                left join tblBlue as dis on b.partyid = dis.partyid and MONTH(dis.AppliedDate) = '12' and YEAR(dis.AppliedDate) = @fYear    and dis.CardType = 'K' and b.PartyId = dis.PartyId 

            group by Description,jan.CardType,feb.CardType,mac.CardType,apr.CardType,may.CardType,jun.CardType,jul.CardType,aug.CardType,sep.CardType,oct.CardType,nov.CardType,dis.CardType
```

END

Now the output is like this based on this query:
 https://gyazo.com/29fa98c207e81578cae95dcbaa97e0b9
if count not equal 0 will be display 2 same result name but the count value different 1 name will get all 0 but another one will have count value.

aspected is like :
https://gyazo.com/e163473da7dd16aa798f431e42588406

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to join the same table 12 times to count the records, something like this should work:

```
select
   @fYear as [Year],
   main.Description,
   sum(case when MONTH(blue.AppliedDate) = 1 then 1 else 0 end)) as Jan_Collection,
   sum(case when MONTH(blue.AppliedDate) = 2 then 1 else 0 end)) as Feb_Collection,
   ...
from BKM_Requestor as main
  left join BKM_Party as b on  main.requestorid = b.requestorid
  left join tblBlue as blue on b.partyid = blue.partyid and YEAR(blue.AppliedDate) = @fYear and blue.CardType = 'K'
group by main.Description
```

Comment: oh icic.. awesome. Thanks bro

Comment: if i want to combine 2 name and record into 1 record is it can??

Comment: Sorry with that description it's really difficult to figure out what you mean. If you mean something like comma separated lists, look into `for xml path`

Comment: Still no idea about your logic. You should really post a new question with good examples and explanation.